# Phrase search in string, making correct RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, search

I will start straight, here's what I have:

```
var SResults = [];
function ActivateSearch(s) {
    SResults = [];

    for (var key in Products){
        if ((' '+Products[key]['n']).search(new RegExp('\\b(('+s+')|('+s+')[s])\\b', 'gi')) > 0) {
            SResults.push(key);
        }
    }
}
ActivateSearch('trampoline cover');
```

With this function I try to find word or phrases in Products[key]['n'], which is some kind of title ex. "Trampoline rain cover 6ft lenght plus extras".

Now it has very basic working principle of looking for every single word of search phrase in mentioned title.

**Problems:**

If there is title trampoline rain cover, and search term is: trampoline cover - no matches.

**Question:**

How to change regex to match result described above?

Comment: You need a backend with a search engine that can understand natural language. Otherwise, you would need to customize the regex for different input.

Comment: Yeah, to solve the problems I changed my regexp to: new RegExp('\\b(('+s+')|('+s+')[s])\\b', 'gi')

Answer (score 1):

Another option would have been to `split` and use alternation with positive lookaheads and word boundaries, such as:

```
^((?=.*\btrampoline\b)|(?=.*\bcover\b)).*$
```

```js
const regex = /^((?=.*\btrampoline\b)|(?=.*\bcover\b)).*$/gmi;
const str = `Trampoline rain cover 6ft lenght plus extras
Rain cover 6ft lenght plus extras
Trampoline rain 6ft lenght plus extras
Cover trampoline rain 6ft lenght plus extras
Covers trampolines rains 6ft lenght plus extras
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
 m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
  if (groupIndex == 0)
   console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
 });
}
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/THUtFU/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/THUtFU/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---